# c# 9.0 records and nullability

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, record-classes

I'm trying out the new record features using latest .Net5

```
  public record Rec {
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
    //public Rec(string name, int id) => (Name, Id) = (name, id);
  }
```

I get

> warning CS8618: Non-nullable field 'Name' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the field as nullable.

So a constructor is not generated whereas I understood that is a feature of records ?
and why not the same warning for `Id` ?
If I unremark the ctor above the warning goes away (which makes sense)

Also if I do instead:

```
public record Rec(string Name, int Id);
```

There are no warnings.

EDIT

so it seems the two forms of creating a record (longer vs shorter syntax) are different, the short version makes the fields public and also adds a ctor whereas the first one does not. I can't find a reference to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So a constructor is not generated whereas I understood that is a feature of records ?

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md): A Primary Constructor is synthesized for all Value Parameters of the Parameter List for the Positional Record.

Your first example doesn't have a Parameter List and thus doesn't have Value Parameters, therefore it is not a Positional Record, and therefore it doesn't have a Primary Constructor.

> and why not the same warning for `Id` ?

Because the [default constructor for `int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#default-constructors) is, and always has been, `0`, not `null`. This isn't really specific to `record`s, this has always been the case, since before C# 1.0.

Comment: Unfortunately your documentation link is 404ing now

Comment: Updated [documentation link](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-9.0/records.md)